# When and for which component is the DOM created in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, dom

Does each Angular component have its own DOM? Or is it only one DOM for the`index.html`, and only the component selector inside the `index.html` have their template elements in the DOM?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the trick:

Create an angular app, create a few components,  use them in the app and Run the app:

You can check the actual DOM of the entire page by inspecting the page on your browser under Elements tab.

I had already done that and the result is:

Every component you're seeing on the screen is part of the actual DOM. So basically, though not sure but I am assuming based on my checks, All components are part of the index.html DOM.

I have tested this by viewing the ELements of the [angular.io](https://angular.io/) site and I found that every component displayed on the screen is part of the DOM.

Comment: So any created component which is there, but not displayed on the screen/ not used will not have a DOM, right?

Comment: The screen renders elements with values and visuals, you may have elements which are part of the DOM but not displayed. e.g you can have a div without any content and it's still part of the DOM on that particular page. But with Angular, Only components triggered by the url or the ones used within the main component(owning the url) will be part of the DOM at that url Instance. Everything else that is not used within the rendered/applied components is not part of the DOM at that Instance.

Comment: The idea is to again visit the angular.io website and switch pages and inspect the Elements while switching and it will show you the magic firsthand.